# Mobx observable properties set in componentDidMount are not being rendered in textarea

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I just heard about Mobx as a state management library a few hours ago.  I decided to give it a try by writing the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {observable} from 'mobx';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

var appState = observable({athlete_name:"Cy Young"});
@observer
export default class App extends React.Component
{
  componentDidMount()
  {
    appState["athlete_name"] = "Babe Ruth"; // this variable/property will be loaded via a REST API http request
  }
  render() {

    console.log(appState["athlete_name"]);
    return (
    <form>
      <h1>{appState["athlete_name"]}</h1>
      <textarea>{appState["athlete_name"]}</textarea>
      <textarea defaultValue={appState["athlete_name"]} />
      <textarea defaultValue="Babe Ruth" />
    </form>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

But for some reason, the first two `textarea` prints `Cy Young`.  The last `textarea`, `h1` and `console.log(appState["athlete_name"])` prints `Babe Ruth` value as expected.   Why is `Cy Young` not being replaced by `Babe Ruth` in two of the textareas? What have I done wrong?

Comment: defaultValue is meant to set an initial value, that's all. That's why your input does not update after you update your state. You want to use "value" if you want it to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<textarea value={appState["athlete_name"]}></textarea>
```

HTML form elements work a little bit differently from other DOM elements in React.
See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)